# Checking if two diagrams have isomorphic colimits

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Consider the infinite diagrams:
$$
C_1\to C_2 \to \cdots \to C_n \to \cdots 
$$
$$
D_1\to D_2 \to \cdots \to D_n \to \cdots 
$$
in some category, and suppose both colimits exist.

How do I check if the colimits are isomorphic? Is there a standard way, or even a definition?

Comment: No, there is no "standard way"... Given $X$, $X'$, $Y$, $Y'$, how do you check if $X \times Y$ and $X' \times Y'$ are isomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

To prove two (co-)limits are isomorphic, we usually show that one (co-)limit satisfies the universal property of the other one and vice versa.